# asp.net jQuery проверка переменной

Tags: jquery, asp.net

Раньше обработчик был такой:

```
<button id="showEmailNotification" class="k-button">Email</button><br />

<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {

        var notification = $("#notification").data("kendoNotification");

        $("#showEmailNotification").click(function(){
            notification.show({
                title: "New E-mail",
                message: "You have 1 new mail message!"
            }, "info");
        });
```

Но сейчас мне необходимо сделать автоматическое срабатывание, т.е. проверять содержаться ли ошибки и возвращать нужный результат. Написал так:

```
if ($(@ViewData.ModelState.IsValid))
{
    notification.show({
        title: "Wrong Password",
        message: "Please enter your password again."
    }, "error");
} else
{
    notification.show({
        message: "Upload Successful"
    }, "upload-success");
}
```

Но как только он на этой строчке `if ($(@ViewData.ModelState.IsValid))`
сразу завершает скрипт. Как исправить?

Comment: смотрели ошибки в консоли браузера?

Answer (score 1):

`@ViewData.ModelState.IsValid` срендерится в `"True"` или `"False"` в зависимости от значения свойства `IsValid`, т.к. такие значения возвращает метод [Boolean.ToString()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/atahsch6(v=vs.110).aspx)

На клиенте получается:

```
if ($(True))
{
    //...
} else
{
    //...
}
```

JS-интерпретатор никакого `True` или `False` не знает. Только `true` и `false`.
Проблема решается следующим образом:

```
@ViewData.ModelState.IsValid.ToString().ToLower()
```

Добавлю, что Ваш код написан неверен:

1. Зачем в функцию jQuery передаете булевское значение? Эта функция на такие параметры всегда будет возвращать массив, состоящий из этого параметра, т.е. `$(true) -> [true]` или `$(false) -> [false]`. Из этого следует, что в условие if'а вы передадите объект, который затем преобразуется в булевское значение, а т.к. он не является ни `0`, ни `NaN`, ни `""`, ни `null`, ни `undefined`, то преобразование вернет `true`. Поэтому у Вас всегда будет выполняться первый блок оператора if.
2. Вы перепутали блоки: при валидных данных, с вашим кодом будет показываться ошибка.

В итоге у Вас должно быть:

```
if (!@ViewData.ModelState.IsValid.ToString().ToLower()) {
    notification.show({
        title: "Wrong Password",
        message: "Please enter your password again."
    }, "error");
} else {
    notification.show({
        message: "Upload Successful"
    }, "upload-success");
}
```

Если данный код выполняется на клиенте один раз и не является телом в какой-нибудь функции, то я бы рендерил нужный блок сразу на сервере:

```
@if (!ViewData.ModelState.IsValid)
{
    <text>
        notification.show({
            title: "Wrong Password",
            message: "Please enter your password again."
        }, "error");
   </text>
}
else
{
    <text>
        notification.show({
            message: "Upload Successful"
        }, "upload-success");
    </text>
}
```